# how to add arrays to Event in #appcelerator

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm trying to create a guestlist by having users send their `user_id` to an array in a `custom_field` in the `Event` object in appcelerator.

```
Cloud.Events.update({
    event_id: event.id
    custom_fields: {'guestlistarray':guestlist }
}, function (e) { 
    if (e.success) {
        var event = e.events[0];
        alert('You added it, maybe');
    } else {
        alert('Error:\n' +
            ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
    }
});
```

I have tried this by updating the event (by the person who wants to apply) by only sending information to the custom field, I have tried pushing in values but all it does is completely replace the `guestlistarray`. I need it to append continuously so that users keep adding to the `guestlistarray`, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to read the array value from the current record, then push the additional value to the returned array, then update... That *should* work.

The other item to investigate is using 'checkins'. This let's a user 'checkin' or 'checkout' of an event, thus automatically creating a 'guest list'. Then you can query checkins for event x, would give you a list of everyone.

Ray

Comment: any chance you could solve this one Ray http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35020543/how-to-show-details-from-arrowdb-for-individual-objects-appcelerator